# TypeScript - type of function with variable number of parameters

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type called **OnClick** that accepts a variable number of types as arguments. How would I go about to make this work? I want to be able to use parameters of different types.

```
type OnClick<..> = (..) => void;

// usage:
const onClick: OnClick<string, number> = (key, value) => {...}
const onClick2: OnClick<SomeType, AnotherType> = (someThing, anotherThing) => {...}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constraint to `T` to declare it as tuple and then use it to type `args`:

```
type OnClick<T extends any[]> = (...args: T) => void;

// usage:
const onClick: OnClick<[string, number]> = (key, value) => {}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to specify types in an array?

Comment: I think no. Even the suggested solution is an workaround.

Comment: What would you prefer instead of the tuple?